# I am unable to get CSS to apply to print table

Tags: function, printing, media

I am new to Javascript and still learning.

I have a Javascript function that prints a table. I am using @media print{} to apply CSS to the printed table. No matter where I put the CSS, I am unable to get it to apply.

I have written CSS for table, th, td, iframe. And have moved it within the #printTable{}, and {display}, and other locations within the  tab.

````
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>Print CSS</title>

       <link rel="stylesheet" href="SSG.css" type="text/css" 
     media="screen"> 

    <style>
    @media print {
          * {display: none;}
            #printableTable {display: block;}

        table,th,td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            }

            th,td {
            height: 150px;
            width: 150px
            }

       }
       </style>
   </head>

   <body>

   <div>
     <h1><b><center>This is a test page for printing</center></b><hr 
       color="#00cc00" width="95%"></h1>
    <button class="Button Button--outline" 
    onclick="printDiv()">Print</button>
      <p> Print Table </p>
      <div id="printableTable">
        <table>
          ```
        </table>
      </div>
      <iframe name="print_frame" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" 
    src="about:blank"></iframe>
    </div>
        <script>
           function printDiv() {
             window.frames["print_frame"].document.body.innerHTML = 
             document.getElementById("printableTable").innerHTML;
             window.frames["print_frame"].window.focus();
             window.frames["print_frame"].window.print();
           }
        </script>
    </body>
````

I would like to understand where to put the CSS so it will apply to the printed table and if I need to create a CSS Selector that applies to  or window.frames["print_frame"]